# Is there a way to tell doctrine not to touch specific tables?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Every time I run `doctrine:migrations:diff` to generate migration for my changes it always includes removal of a few tables that are not handled by doctrine eg.:

```
$this->addSql('DROP TABLE messenger_messages');
$this->addSql('DROP TABLE monitoring');
```

Is there a way to tell doctrine that specific tables do not belong to him so doctrine will stop trying to drop them every time?

Answer (score 5):

You can find your answer in the docs : https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#manual-tables

Short answer : add prefix to your custom tables, then configure this prefix (for instance if your custom tables start by 't_') :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        schema_filter: ~^(?!t_)~
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use a regex to exclude tables from doctrine field of view.
To specify a list of tables that should not be touched by doctrine just add this to config:

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    schema_filter: ~^(?!(messenger_messages|monitoring|foo|bar)$)~
```

This will prevent doctrine from manipulating those four tables:

- messenger_messages
- monitoring
- foo
- bar

Thanks @Diabetic Nephropathy for hinting the way with regex.

Answer (score 2):

When having multiple connections it needs to be set for each connection:

```yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                schema_filter: '~^(?!messenger_messages)~'
```